# Does blackberry applications support 9 patch images?

Tags: blackberry, drawable, assets

I want to  know if 9 patch images can be used in blackberry. I need to design button images.
Also need to know more information on assets creation, assets library structure in blackberry.

Comment: http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/creating-login-page-with-border-in-bb.html

Answer (score 1):

> Does blackberry applications support 9
>   patch images?

No. At least there is no BB APIs available right out of the box. So you will have to write your own code for this.